# Opening an android app and gzip decompression

Tags: android, operating-system, zlib, dalvik

So I've found out that when opening a program on an android device, there is some decompression happening. I'm trying to figure out where the zlib library is being called from. My hunch is that zygote or some forked part of the VM is making the call. Also, everytime I open the program, the same file (or a resource) that is the same size is being decompressed. Maybe it's the saved state of the application ?

**Here's what I found:**

I/Noodles( 1817): INFLATE SYSTEM: PID: 1817, Bytes In: 780, Bytes Written: 2652

In this case 1817 is com.android.Gallery2 . I've searched the android sources of the com.android.Gallery2 and I haven't found a resource that was size 780. I also took the .apk and unzipped it looking for the resource and didn't find anything.

Do you have any ideas where this call maybe coming from?

**EDIT**

Sorry I should have realized this... Libpng is doing all the inflating before onCreate / onResume method is called. I wonder what class is calling it though.

Comment: If you have the developer options enabled (http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#device-developer-options), and the target app is debuggable (which gallery won't be by default unless you're on a developer device -- needs a manifest flag), you can set a "wait for debugger on startup" flag.  This is normally used to debug things like `onCreate()`, but may well pause before this fires.

Comment: Looks like the decompression is happening before onCreate / onResume. I'm going to take a look at the Activity state code. I still feel like this is something the system is doing. Thanks for the idea